# 'ARView' is unavailable in xrOS

Tags: ios, realitykit, visionos

Working with Apple Vision Pro SDK. When trying to reference ARView in ARKit I get `ARView` is unavailable in xrOS. But the docs for ARView say it's available in visionOS 1.0+ Beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in the Apple documentation. ARView for SwiftUI is a view working with UIKit's wrapper (UIViewRepresentable) and AppKit's wrapper (NSViewRepresentable). Loading ARView in visionOS causes an error (Xcode 15 beta 3). This seems quite logical to me, because the scene's assembly point in visionOS is no longer `arView.scene`, but make / update closure's `content` parameter (***RealityViewContent***).

[image]

In visionOS, [RealityView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76747287/what-is-the-difference-between-model3d-and-realityview-in-visionos/76747520#76747520) and `Model3D` view are used instead.