# What is the difference between Model3D and RealityView in visionOS?

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

I think RealityView should be able to do more fancy stuffs, but I still want to figure out the exact differences between them. For now, they are just too similar to each other, e.g. they both need an Entity name to get initialized. I want to know when a Model3D is just enough, and when we must use a RealityView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### RealityView

Standard practice for Apple engineers is to give views several initializers. visionOS `RealityView` isn't an exception here. Let's take a look at RealityView's `init(make:update:attachments:)` initializer with three closures, where you can:

- create, set up and configure the initial 3D scene's content (`make` closure)
- update scene's content in response to changes in view's state (optional `update` closure)
- implement ViewBuilder of attachment views to use in 3D scene (`attachments` closure)

There's also `init(make:update:placeholder:)` initializer with a ***placeholder***.

Use RealityView to asynchronously load (it's an optional action) and display a rich 3D content in RealityKit app. RealityView passes a struct conforming to RealityViewContentProtocol to the `make` and `update` closures, which you can use to add and remove RealityKit's entities to a scene. Entities must be 3D primitives, `.usdz` models, or scenes from Reality Composer Pro.

```
RealityView { content, attachments in
    // code
} update: { content, attachments in
    // code           
} attachments: {
    // code         
}
```

Just like in ARSCNView (it's a SceneKit's symbiosis of AR and VR), you are not obliged to use an anchor, however, using [anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893075/what-is-aranchor-exactly/52899502#52899502) gives you the opportunity to implement robust AR scenarios – such as `image tracking`, `plane tracking`, `hand tracking`, etc.

Let's see how RealityView looks in code and what base object will be printed in console:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            if let model = try? await Entity.load(named: "car") {
                model.scale /= 10
                
                let anchor = AnchorEntity()
                anchor.addChild(model)
                content.add(anchor)
                
                print(content)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, `RealityView` is rather a RealityKit's view for visionOS SwiftUI apps where you get an access to a scene's assembly point. And don't forget that anchors are an important part of the `RealityView` hierarchical structure, which isn't the case in Model3D.

[image]

---

---

### Model3D

SwiftUI's Model3D view is simpler than RealityView, and is used to asynchronously load and display a model from the specified URL (`.usdz` or `.reality` models) or from app's bundle. Until the model loads, SwiftUI displays a placeholder. The resulted model is contained in `ResolvedModel3D` view. Working with Model3D view you are unable to decompose a 3D scene like in RealityView.

```
Model3D(url: url) { phase in
    if let model = phase.model {
        // code
    } else if phase.error != nil {
        // error description    
    } else {
        // placeholder
    }
}
```

Just like RealityView, Model3D view has several initializers.

Let's see how `init(named:bundle:content:placeholder:)` initializer with a ***placeholder*** @ViewBuilder looks in code and what base object will be printed in console:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Model3D(named: "car") { model in
            model.resizable()

            let _ = print(model)
        } placeholder: {
            ProgressView()
        }
    }
}
```

In other words, `Model3D` is the SwiftUI's 3D view holding RealityKit's scene.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was wondering where AnchorEntity is when playing with RealityView. Looks like Apple does not expose it on purpose? Previously we must set Anchor type in Reality Composer but I didn't see any Anchor stuff in Reality Composer Pro.

Comment: Yep, RealityView works the same way as great old SceneKit's ARSCNView (with or without anchors).

Comment: @AndyJazz How to `aspectFit` entity in `RealityView`? Is possible to do something similar as `model.resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` for `Model3D`?

Answer (score 0):

It is also interesting to note that all instances of RealityView and Model3D share a unique hierarchy, regardless of where they are located in SwiftUI.

Using the `.parent` property of any entity, one can climb to a common root named `Window Context Entity` and there are also a number of intriguing new entity types in the tree like `CALayerEntity`